# How to manually uninstall urllib, urllib2, requests python packages?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, python, libraries

I'm having a problem with urllib, urllib2 and requests, three python libraries.

I use Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and python 2.6.5 (we can use with python) (but I had installed manually, **after** the problem, python 2.5.6 and python 2.7, respectively python2.5, python2.7).

Initially my packages worked fine, but in some point, maybe updating the kernel, not sure, nothing works.

The strange that is if I run python using root, the commands works fine (please see this question in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779103/strange-return-using-the-requests-python-package-how-to-fix)), but using the common user don't works.

I think the problem is, I had installed this packages using **pip** and **easy_install** with root, not using the common user. Initially I couldnt install with my user, so I tried root and worked, but with the problem above showed in the stackoverflow question.

So I would like how to remove, probably manually (looks like or Ubuntu 10.04.04 don't have a way to easy uninstall the packages, using pip and easy_install, or I don't know one), this libraries of my system.

Comment: “nothing works”, “don't works”: ok, so what happens if you try to use them? You get error messages? Your computer blows up? Copy-paste the exact commands you ran and all the messages you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issues with the python package module installation using root login or some other user other than root.

Anyway you can uninstall the python package using pip and easy_install as below.

```
#pip uninstall packagename

#easy_install -m PackageName
```

Comment: Well, this should work, but unfortunally, neither pip and easy_install recognize these commands, probably because the stable packages to Ubuntu 10.04.4 Long Time Support don't have these commands.

Comment: I had changed to 12.04 and this isn't a problem to me anymore, so I will embrace this answer.